# Perforce -- How to obtain a revision number of a file given a specific time period

Tags: perforce, revision

I am interested to obtain the revision number of a file given a specific date or time period in Perforce.

If I use `p4 files`, I find that if there are no new submissions on that time period, the comment returned when the p4 command is executed is:

```
no revision(s) after that date
```

Full example as below:

```
% p4 files //depot/project/file_a.c@2018/03/06,@2018/03/07 
//depot/project/file_a.c@2018/03/06,@2018/03/07 - no revision(s) after that date
```

But the information I am looking for is the revision number of `file_a.c` between `2018/03/06` and `2018/03/07`, regardless whether there are submission during that dates or otherwise. Something like this would be good:

```
//depot/project/file_a.c#31 - edit change 12345678
```

Am I using the right Perforce command? Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It sounds like what you're really asking for is what the latest revision of the file was as of 2018/03/07:

```
% p4 files //depot/project/file_a.c@2018/03/07
```

Comment: Cool, simpler than I thought. Thanks for the answer!